# Parse a function call stored in a XML file to a class in C#

Tags: c#, xml, reflection

I want to get a function out of my XML file to my class. Is this somehow possible? And could someone give me an example. The Labox is a public static class.

I want the "Labox.SetDigitalOutBit(9,1) in a XML-file":

```
using LABOX;

namespace Project
{
    class Myclass
    {
         private void ProductionlineOn
         {
             Labox.SetDigitalOutBit(9, 1);
         }
    }
}
```

I figured out this is what had to stay in my XML file (I hope)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <methodCall>
        <methodName>Labox.SetDigitalOutBit</methodName>
        <params>
            <param>
                <value>
                    <i4>9</i4>
               </value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <value>
                   <i4>1</i4>
                </value>
           </param>
         </params>
    </methodCall>
```

Comment: What *get function to class* means? You want to generate class, or you want to execute function which already exists in class and you have class instance?

Comment: I want to execute a function which already exists in the class

Comment: You always execute static methods of some `Labox` class defined in same namespace as code which calls method?

Comment: Yes I always execute static methohs of the labox class in the same namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you should provide information about type which method you want to invoke. I suggest you to add appropriate element to xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
  <typeName>SomeNamespace.Labox</typeName>
  <methodName>SetDigitalOutBit</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <i4>9</i4>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <i4>1</i4>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

Then you should parse this data from xml:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
string typeName = (string)xdoc.Root.Element("typeName");
string methodName = (string)xdoc.Root.Element("methodName");
object[] parameters =
    xdoc.Root.Element("params")
        .Elements("param")
        .Select(p => (object)(int)p.Element("value").Element("i4"))
        .ToArray();
```

And call method with reflection:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
var flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;
var method = type.GetMethod(methodName, flags);
method.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

Of course, when you are getting parameters from xml, you should analyze type of parameter (integer, string, etc) and create instance of appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Reflection to get the Method which name you extract from the XML file.

```
object[] arrayOfParameters = ...;

// Get Method and Invole it
MethodInfo mInfo = typeof(YourClass).GetMethod(methodExtractedFromXml);

object result = mInfo.Invoke(yourObject, arrayOfParameters);
```

If you invoke a static method. In the GetMethod specify BindingFlags.Static and instead of yourObject, specify null.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about the Invoke

Comment: I dont really get this one, what do I exactly need to fill in here (...).

Comment: @user3201911: Any questions left?

Comment: @user3201911: Please don't forget to vote for answers you like. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote